# Rails 4 assets not loading in heroku after 'rake assets:precompile'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, loading, assets, precompile

This is driving me insane! My app works properly on the local server, but when I uploaded to heroku, the css and js files didn't update. I read to precompile using rake assets:precompile to fix the issue, but then I uploaded to heroku again and now all my assets aren't loading at all! I've tried all variations of precompile, installed 12factor gem, turned some config settings from false to true, still not happening! When i look at the console, it says

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
    global code (application-38ccb09605964287831a37a0d9faf188.js, line 1)

but I do have Jquery! it works fine on local! I dunno what I'm doing wrong guys.

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.log_level = :info
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Comment: can you run `heroku logs` and show its content ?

Comment: its kind of long so i put it inside a google doc.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13ymjsdT2fvamFmGvKvsir582u4dcNL27-1qxWZpoV6g/edit

Comment: ok..i logged on this morning and now my app on local doesn't work now either..mustve have been cached or something.

Comment: `config.assets.debug = true` seems to have solved the problem for local but still not working on heroku

Comment: running `$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` made my heroku app work now. so i guess problem is fixed..

Comment: so please answer your own question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running `$RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` made my heroku app work now. so i guess problem is fixed..

sorry, I don't have an explanation on why it works

Comment: Thanks! This was a really frustrating problem, and this solved it! Who would have thought that just precompiling the assets locally and pushing them to Heroku would work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run

```
    $ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    $ git add .
    $ git commit -am "assets precompiled locally"
    $ git push heroku master
```